# NodeJS with Docker: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/usr/src/app/'

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

I'm mostly trying to understand how I can troubleshoot/understand how the files are packaged into the docker container when building the NodeJS app. I have a NodeJS project that has the following directory structure:

The docker file content is as below

```
# Use an existing node image as the base
FROM node:14

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the files
COPY . .

# Set the command to start the web server
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]

# Expose the port that the web server will listen on
EXPOSE 5000
```

The docker-compose up file is as below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node_app1:
    container_name: container1
    image: a/app1
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app

  node_app2:
    container_name: container2
    image: a/app2
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

index.js for container1

```
const express = require("express")
const fs = require("fs")
const app = express();
const axios = require("axios")
const path = require("path")

app.use(express.json());
const fileData = {}
let output = {}
app.post('/checksum', function(request, response){
    let data = request.body;
    fileData.file = data.file
    //response.send(request.body); 
    let filename = fileData.file
    if(filename == ""){
        output = {}
        output.file = "NULL"
        output.error = "Invalid JSON input."
        response.send(output)
        console.log(output)
    }if(filename == null){
        output = {}
        output.file = null
        output.error = "Invalid JSON input."
        response.send(output)
    }
    if(typeof filename !== 'string'){
        output = {}
        output.file = filename
        output.error = "Invalid JSON input."
        response.send(output)
    }else {
        let filePath = path.join('./', filename)
        if(!(fs.existsSync(filePath))){
            output = {}
            output.file = fileData.file
            output.error = "File does not exist"
            response.send(output)
            console.log(output)
        }else{
            axios.post("http://container2:8000/", fileData)
                .then(function(res) {
                    let data = res.data
                    output = {}
                    output.file = data.file
                    output.checksum = data.checksum
                    response.send(output)
                    console.log(output)
                })
            
        }
    }   
});


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server started");
  });
```

index.js for container2:

```
const express = require("express")
const fs = require("fs")
const crypto = require("crypto")
const app = express();
const path = require("path")
app.use(express.json());

const fileData = {}
const output ={}
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    let data = request.body;
    fileData.file = data.file
    let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(fileData.file).digest('hex')
    let filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), './', fileData.file)
    fs.readFile(filePath,'utf-8',(err,data)=>{
        if(err)
        console.log(err)
        else{
            let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest('hex')
            output.file = fileData.file
            output.checksum = hash
            response.send(output); 
        } 
    }
    )
      
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("server started");
  });
```

From here I need to get the output checksum if the file is present. but it goes to file not found error eventhough I manually place the file in the conainer1 folder.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/usr/src/app/'] {
container2  |   errno: -2,
container2  |   code: 'ENOENT',
container2  |   syscall: 'open',
container2  |   path: '/app/usr/src/app/'
container2  | }
```

I think the root path is the problem. I need to know how to give the root path for this so that the file should be given as checksum.

Comment: You seem to have included a PNG file at the end of your question instead of the error message.  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image with the text of the error?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run two separate applications, but then you have `volumes:` blocks that overwrite the entire application source tree in both containers with the same local directory.  Does deleting those `volumes:` blocks help things?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have modified the question and Deleting the volumes also did not solve the error

Comment: The `/app/usr/src/app/` file path looks odd (and not anything that Docker would create on its own); have you tried to dig into where it comes from?  The container2 code has a major security problem in that the unsanitized path can be used to read any file, like `../../../../etc/passwd`.